# Ancho tabla word java

Tags: java, apache-poi

Tengo :

```
XWPFTable header = document.createTable(1 , 2); 
header.getRow(0).getCell(0).setColor("dbdbdb")
header.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("titulo")
header.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("valor1")
```

Cuando genera el word el ancho de la tabla se adapta al texto, pero me gustaria darle un `30%` al titulo y un `70%` al valor, es posible?